# Any way to track custom statistics in locust

Tags: python, locust

Locust is a great and simple load testing tool. By default it only tracks response times and content length from which it can deduce RPS, etc. Is there any way to track custom statistics in locust as well?

In my case a site Im testing returns couple of stats via headers. For example a count of SQL queries within a request. It would be very helpful to track some of these statistics in conjunction to tracking standard response times.

I do not see any way to do that in locust however. Is there a simple way for doing that?

Only customization I could see is setting [url names in a request in docs](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.clients.HttpSession.request).

Manually storing some of the stats is not that straight forward either as locust is distributed so would like to avoid doing anything custom.

edit

There is an [example](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/events.py#L36-L62) how custom stats can be passed around however that does not show up in the UI and requires custom export. Any way to add additional data in locust which will get logged both in UI and data export?

Maybe something like:

```
class MyTaskSet(TaskSet):
    @task
    def my_task(self):
        response = self.client.get("/foo")
        self.record(foo=response.headers.get('x-foo'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no *simple* way of visualizing custom data in Locust. However, by looking at https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/locust/main.py#L370, you could easily replace main locust run function and inject some custom logic to https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/locust/web.py. This seem to be a low hanging fruit for the Locust devs to make this part of code more adjustable out of the box so I'd suggest opening issue in their GitHub.